# Android-Need draw a diagonal line like label

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-xml

I need to draw a diagonal line like New label on the top of view. I want to use xml or canvas to draw it. Is it possible? Can anyone help me suggest to me the solution?

Thanks.

[image: diagonal line]

Answer (score 2):

It can be created using xml drawable. Here is my xml drawable file which you can modify according to your need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="150"
        android:toDegrees="20"
        android:pivotX="20%"
        android:pivotY="10%" >
         <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
             <solid android:color="#ADD588" >
             </solid>

             <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ADD588" />
          </shape>
      </rotate>
   </item>

 </layer-list>
```